# How to alter a global variable from a function called when an event triggers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using NodeJS and node-csv, I'm trying to load rows in a Array. From an example in the module:

```
// node samples/string.js
csv()
    .from.string(
        '#Welcome\n"1","2","3","4"\n"a","b","c","d"', {
            comment: '#'
        })
    .to.array(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
// [ [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] ]
```

But if inside function (data) I try to add each row to an Array defined in the global scope, it doesn't alter it. It's obvious I don't understand JS variables scope, but what's the best pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: show us the part where you alter the global scope var.

Comment: .to.array(function (data) {
        rows.push(data);
    });

Comment: and the part where you define the array in global scope

Comment: var rows = new Array(); before csv()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is altering the rows variable, but the console.log() call is being called before the rows are pushed. You can use the .on('end') event to call a function after they have been pushed.

```
var csv = require('csv');
var rows = new Array();


csv()
    .from.string(
        '#Welcome\n"1","2","3","4"\n"a","b","c","d"', {
            comment: '#'
        })
    .to.array(function (data) {
    rows.push(data);
        console.log(rows);
    }).on('end', function() {
        logRows();
    });

var logRows = function() {
    console.log(rows);
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't seem to alter rows outside the anonymous function. If I call console.log(rows); outside function (data) it's empty.

Comment: I think it is changing the rows, but it's an order issue. Please see my edits coming up.

Comment: I'm using node-async with async.series